How can i use sth like Join for google charts in react
I have two different data sets:
[[ "Time", "Value"],[ 1232150400000, 0.000215853211009174 ],...] and [[ "Time", "Value"],[ 1230940800000, 0.01 ],...]
The x values are not exact the same but fit on the same x axis and i want to use something like:
joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
to join them but i cant use that in react. Is there anything similar?
I tried google.visualization.data.join but it did not work in react
